# How do I integrate this rational function?

Tags: integration, polynomials

Evaluate this integral
$$I=∫\dfrac{1-x^2}{x^4+x^2+1}dx$$ (with $x$ is different from 0).
I tried divided both the numerator and denominator by $x^2$, and I got $$∫\dfrac{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+1}dx.$$
I then put $t=x+1/x$ and got this $$I=∫-\dfrac{dt}{t^2-1}.$$
Finally I got the answer
$$\dfrac12{\ln|-x^2-\dfrac{1}{x^2}-1|}+C$$
or the alternative form is
$$\dfrac{\ln\left(\left|x^2+x+1\right|\right)+\ln\left(\left|x^2-x+1\right|\right)-2\ln\left(\left|x\right|\right)}{2}+C. $$ Where did I make mistake? Because when I compute the function, the result is different $$\dfrac{\ln\left(x^2+x+1\right)-\ln\left(x^2-x+1\right)}{2}+C.$$

Answer (score 4):

Note
$$ \int\frac1{t^2-1}dt=\frac12(\ln|t-1|-\ln|t+1|)+C. $$
Now you plug in $t=x+\frac1x$ to get the result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but did you forget the minus ?^^ or I did wrong?

Comment: You can put the negative sign.

Comment: Okay^^I will check it

Answer (score 3):

Since xpaul answered your question. Notice that another way is using partial fraction and we get
$$\frac{1-x^2}{x^4+x^2+1}=\frac{1}2\underbrace{\left(\frac{1+2x}{1+x+x^2}\right)}_{(*)}+\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\left(\frac{1-2x}{1-x+x^2}\right)}_{(**)}$$
For $(*)$ substitution $u(x)=1+x+x^2$ and for $(**)$ substitution $v(x)=1-x+x^2$ in the integration.

Edit:

- $x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+1)^2-x^2=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$.
- In partial fraction we want find constant $A,B,C$ and $D$ such that
  $$\frac{1-x^2}{x^4+x^2+1}=\frac{A+Bx}{x^2+x+1}+\frac{C+Dx}{x^2-x+1}$$ That implies logically that
  $$1-x^2=(A+Bx)(x^2+x+1)+(C+Dx)(x^2-x+1)$$
  Then, a way to find the constants is using roots of the polynomial (in this case it is not useful) and other way it is solving the linear system with the coefficients (expanding and grouping). The second method work here.

Comment: Hello, can you explain how did you subtitute x^4+x^2+1 into (1+x+x^2)(1-x+x^2)?^^

Comment: Yes, of course. Notice that $$x^4+x^2+1=x^4+x^2+1+x^2-x^2=(x^4+2x^2+1)-x^2=(x^2+1)^2-x^2=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1).$$ The old trick of adding and subtracting something convenient.

Comment: wait how did you use partial fraction notice that x^2+x+1=0 and x^2-x+1=0 don't have real solution

Comment: That is a good question. I added more details to my post. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer, and I will really appreciate if you can help me with the "solving the linear system with the coefficients"(I think I haven't learnt solving this type of linear equation yet).One more time, I appreciate your post.( I am kinda bad at English btw).

Comment: hmn I tried and had this B+D=0 ; A+B+C-D=-1; A+B-C+D=0; A+C=1 => A=1/2 C=1/2 B=-1 D=-1.Did i get the right answers?

Comment: I fixed the typo, thank you user2661923. On other hand, we should have $B=1$. @Viole

Comment: Okay^^ I will check it.